# Разнородные классы, интерфейс и бд

Tags: c#

Итак, есть некая коллекция интерфейсов. Каждый элемент в ней - это разные задачи релизующие интерфейс `ITask`:

```
   public interface ITask
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Type { get; set; }
        void Run();
        void Edit();
        void Save();
    }
```

У каждого класса реализующие этот интерфейс свои задачи и соответсвенно свои поля, свои вьюхи для настройки и т.д., обобщить всё это не видится возможным и разумным. Вокруг этой концепции было накручена логика и она работала, пока не пришло время написать сохранение задач в БД. И тут началось, вся кривота этого сценарию полезла во все поля. Пришел к концепции - буду сериализовать в JSON в Базу и баста. Так себе идея, но лучше ничего не придумал. Чем дальше в лес тем больше появлялось костылей и велосипедов. В итоге код превратился к адскую неработающию и сложную в отладке кашу. Несколько дней я вертел это так и так. Иду с поклоном к вам. Подскажите, как нормальные люди решают подобные задачи?

Comment: Ну, навскидку первая идея — почему бы каждому типу задач не сериализироваться в отдельную, предназначенную для этого типа таблицу? Тогда можно будет костыль с JSON'ом убрать.

Comment: Ну мне эта мысль приходила, но тоже не самое удобное дело - собирай все это в одну коллекцию потом из дюжины таблиц.

Comment: Зато чистое решение. Если у вас разнородные данные, естественно, что они хранятся в «разнородных» таблицах. Сборка в одну коллекцию прямо отображает вашу предметную область: разнородные задачи в общей коллекции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate позволяет мапить в одну таблицу наследников одного класса без заморочек. Заодно запрос по коллекции работает без джойнов.

В качестве примера, разные логины замапленные в одну таблицу:

```
  public class LoginMap : ClassMap<Account.Login>
  {
    public LoginMap()
    {
      Not.LazyLoad();
      Id(x => x.Id);
      Map(x => x.Name);
      Map(x => x.Password);
      DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
  }

  public class HentaichanLoginMap : SubclassMap<Manga.Hentaichan.HentaichanLogin>
  {
    public HentaichanLoginMap()
    {
      Not.LazyLoad();
      Map(x => x.UserId);
      Map(x => x.PasswordHash);
      DiscriminatorValue(Manga.Hentaichan.HentaichanLogin.Type.ToString());
    }
  }

  public class GroupleLoginMap : SubclassMap<Manga.Grouple.GroupleLogin>
  {
    public GroupleLoginMap()
    {
      Not.LazyLoad();
      DiscriminatorValue(Manga.Grouple.GroupleLogin.Type.ToString());
    }
  }

  public class AcomicsLoginMap : SubclassMap<Manga.Acomic.AcomicsLogin>
  {
    public AcomicsLoginMap()
    {
      Not.LazyLoad();
      Map(x => x.PasswordHash);
      DiscriminatorValue(Manga.Acomic.AcomicsLogin.Type.ToString());
    }
  }
```

Интерфейсные\поля предка мапятся в самом верху, остальные дополняются для наследников, если оно надо.

В крупном проекте такое руками писать скорее всего уже неудобно и надо делать какой нибудь автогенерируемый мапинг на шаблонах.

Comment: В итоге выяснилось, что Entity тоже может, переписал на классы и всё встало на место. Спасибо!